# Can't find point of interest with geocoding

Tags: javascript, geolocation, google-geocoder

I have a web app where I use javascript google geocoder:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': from }, function(results, status) {
    var from_lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var from_lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
});
```

It finds almost any address, but if I search for some points of interest, I get: ZERO_RESULTS in status.
For example:

```
"Azrieli Center, Derech Menachem Begin, Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel"
```

How can I change my code in order to find this kind of place?

Answer (score 0):

Businesses are excluded from Geocoding API, so you have to use a [places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests) of Maps JavaScript API in order to find POI like this one.

Please have a look at this example on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/jayabe/edit?html,output